# Flask-Migrate only save the database，how to save the data?

Tags: python, flask

When i read the book-Flask Web Development, the chapter 5.11. I  do the operation,
`python hello.py db migrate -m "initial migration"` and `python hello.py db upgrade`.Then only save the database, the data is disapper, how to save the database and the data together?